# How to get a user on each page refresh? JWT token, MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt, mern

I store JWT in Cookies. In order to get a User every time I refresh the page, I came up with the idea to create a route that will return my logged-in user to App.js:

```
exports.getUserProfile = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    user: user,
  });
});
```

This is where I get User back:

```
useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
```

This is my Route:

```
router
  .route('/myprofile')
  .get(authController.protect, authController.getUserProfile);
```

This is my protect route that returns a user to my req.user and in getUserProfile I get a user (User.getById) (req.user._id):

```
exports.protect = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (!token) {
    return next(
      new AppError('Unauthorized. Please login to access this resource!', 401)
    );
  }

  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'my-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret');
  // after veryfing token, signing ID in req.user of currently logged in user
  req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id); //

  next();
});
```

The problem is that on every page refresh and on whatever page I find that prints errors (such as login there I should print errors if the email is not valid, password etc) .. If I am not logged in and fetch the route getUserProfile always prints an error to me " Unauthorized. Please login to access this resource! " from the protected route. How can I not print it because my login route is not protected .. Also when the sign in is not printed, I immediately get the user.name in the header, but only after the refresh page.

Comment: I properly didn't understood what you did there. You can use separate routes for protected and public, such as "/public" you will not use the auth middleware, for others you will use the auth middleware. Another solution would be you can check req.originalUrl, and use condition there. Although I would prefer the first option

Comment: If I don't use protected middleware I don't have access to the user in req.body in authController.getUserProfile

Comment: but you will have access in middleware. I am saying use your conditions in middleware